# Can I break the long line in emacs (non windows) to the next line?

Tags: emacs, split, line

[image]

With emacs (non windows), I see '$' mark at the end of the line when the terminal width is narrow. Is there a way to break the long line to the next line instead of showing the '$' mark?

### ADDED

M-x auto-fill-mode works fine for text-mode, but with org-mode, the $ mark remains with the auto-fill-mode.

Comment: Give [Cocoa Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/) a try, it'll give you a better experience than Emacs running in Terminal.app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get emacs to break long lines into multiple shorter lines with `M-x fill-paragraph` or `M-x fill-region`.  You can also make this the default behavior with `M-x auto-fill-mode`.

Answer (score 14):

You can disable line truncation with `M-x` `set-variable` `truncate-lines` `nil`.

You can also put in your .emacs `(setq-default truncate-lines nil)` to have that setting by default.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question, it should've been accepted instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can customize the `word-wrap` variable to visually wrap lines. This should be similar to `longlines-mode`, except it would use the buffer width rather than the fill column for wrapping.

You can alternatively use `visual-line-mode` to both enable word wrapping, and also "Redefine simple editing commands to act on visual lines, not logical lines", which addresses a point that nominolo mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Set it for all buffers:

```
(setq truncate-lines nil)
```

Set it just for specific mode(org-mode for instance):

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (setq truncate-lines nil)))
```

Answer (score 2):

For the current session only use command

```
M-x toggle-truncate-lines
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `truncate-lines` to `nil` will break long lines, but if press `C-n` or `downarrow` the cursor will jump to the next physical line, not the position displayed below the cursor.

When working with Tex, I usually switch on `M-x longlines-mode`.  It has its quirks, but it works reasonably well.